# Is it possible to pass values from function to function in c++?

Tags: c++, function, arguments, return-value

I am new to c++ and I have this question. Is it possible in C++ to take a value from one function and pass it to another or store it in another. Take this example code

```
int randomFunction(){
int x;
cin >> x;
return x;
}

int main(){
cout << "Enter a random number?";
randomFunction()
cout << x;      //I want this to display the return value(x) from randomFunction
return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to display or use the value(x) from randomFunction in the main function. Sort of like passing values from function to function

Comment: hell yess mann !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!111

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use the return value of the function.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int randomFunction()
{
   int x;

   cin >> x;

   return x;
}

int main()
{
   cout << "Enter a random number?";

   int x = randomFunction();
   cout << x;

   return 0;
}
```

Or you can do the same without defining intermediate variable x

```
   cout << randomFunction();
```

Also you can return values from a function by means of declaring parameters as references or pointers. For example

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void randomFunction( int &x )
{
   cin >> x;
}

int main()
{
   cout << "Enter a random number?";

   int x;

   randomFunction( x );

   cout << x;

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function is returning an `int` type so you need to store its return value in an `int` type variable in the caller function if you wanna use it, otherwise the return value will be discarded.   Try this

```
int x = randomFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the return value in a variable and cout the variable.

```
int randomFunction()
{
   int x;
   cin >> x;
   return x;
}

int main()
{
   cout << "Enter a random number?";
   int x = randomFunction();
   cout << x;
   getchar();
   return 0;
}
```

Or you can cout it in the random function

```
    void randomFunction()
    {
       int x;
       cin >> x;
       cout<<x;
    }

    int main()
    {
       cout << "Enter a random number?";
       randomFunction();
       getchar();
       return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
void main()
{
int a,b,c=10;
a=fun1(c);
b=fun3();
cout<<a+b;
}
int fun1(int x)
{
int y;
y=fun2(x);
return y;
}
int fun2(int z)
{
return z+z;
}
int  fun3(int w)
{
return w+1;
}
```

hell yea it works !(i did'nt try it though )